# Eclipse CVS setup problem - Error validating location

Tags: eclipse, cvs, eclipse-wtp

I'm trying to configure a second Eclipse installation to access the Eclipse WTP sources. I think I'm doing exactly what I did successfully in another installation, but I get the following error:[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it with your settings and it works fine for me. Could it be a firewall issue? Another option for getting the sources would be to use the Git mirrors (at the very bottom of http://dev.eclipse.org/git/) with [EGit](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/).

Comment: Thanks. The settings also work fine for me in another Eclipse on the same machine, so I don't think it's a firewall issue. It looks like Git only has a partial subset of WTP. I don't see JSDT there.  My workaround is to import the projects, but it would be nice to have the team capabilities in the same Eclipse.

Comment: @Paul: Ah, same machine - that's odd. Perhaps restarting with -clean is worth a try? And JSDT seems to be mirrored in Git: git://dev.eclipse.org/org.eclipse.webtools/org.eclipse.jsdt.git

Comment: No luck with -clean.  I see jsdt in the git list now. I'll try that later if no one has ideas about cvs configuration problem. Thanks.

Comment: I installed a fresh Eclipse, set up my project, and CVS worked fine.